# Como Sumar los Valores de Índices que se Repiten en una Lista 2x2

Tags: python

Teniendo una lista 2x2 con los siguientes valores:

```
litrosCamionAsignado = [[5, 1329], [4, 1386], [1, 1462], [3, 1222], [2, 1445], [3, 1389], [1, 1500], [1, 1419], [5, 1355], [4, 1491], [1, 1427], [4, 1421], [3, 1259], [5, 1489], [5, 1417], [1, 1220], [1, 1291], [2, 1341], [4, 1386], [3, 1467], [1, 1429], [5, 1232], [3, 1343], [1, 1426], [4, 1332], [4, 1494], [3, 1280], [1, 1374], [2, 1376], [4, 1349]]
```

Se deben sumar los valores i[1] de los índices i[0] que se repiten a lo largo de la lista sacando un resultado como el siguiente:

```
totalSuma = [[1, 12548], [2, 4162], [3, 7960], [4, 9859], [5, 6822]
```

La lista 2x2 la obtengo combinando dos listas simples con ZIP:

```
litrosCamionAsignado = [list(x) for x in zip(idCamion, litrosAsignado)]
```

y requiero realizar otras combinaciones y operaciones sobre estas y otras listas, pero solo he podido sumar valores individuales dentro de variables que no me dan como resultado una lista. muestro uno de los intentos que he realizado donde solo saco valores individuales:

```
idCamion = [5, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 5, 4, 1, 4, 3, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4]
    litrosAsignado = [1329, 1386, 1462, 1222, 1445, 1389, 1500, 1419, 1355, 1491, 1427, 1421, 1259, 1489, 1417, 1220, 1291, 1341, 1386, 1467, 1429, 1232, 1343, 1426, 1332, 1494, 1280, 1374, 1376, 1349]
    litrosRegistrado = [1168, 1224, 1379, 1281, 1200, 1320, 1225, 1149, 1424, 1437, 1205, 1297, 1357, 1227, 1263, 1123, 1137, 1374, 1229, 1437, 1290, 1259, 1435, 1104, 1387, 1377, 1294, 1338, 1387, 1208]
    tiemDesAsignado  = [48, 35, 54, 35, 44, 52, 35, 50, 44, 46, 38, 31, 55, 35, 37, 33, 35, 48, 54, 34, 42, 32, 54, 33, 36, 40, 39, 36, 48, 50]
    tiemDesRegistrado = [52, 51, 33, 52, 38, 34, 52, 51, 34, 36, 42, 37, 49, 36, 46, 33, 30, 37, 33, 31, 48, 48, 30, 40, 43, 55, 54, 51, 47, 34]
    
    litrosCamionAsignado = [list(x) for x in zip(idCamion, litrosAsignado)]
    
    litros1Asignado = 0
    litros2Asignado = 0
    litros3Asignado = 0
    litros4Asignado = 0
    litros5Asignado = 0
    
    for i in litrosCamionAsignado:
        if i[0] == 1:
            litros1Asignado = litros1Asignado + i[1]
        elif i[0] == 2:
            litros2Asignado = litros2Asignado + i[1]
        elif i[0] == 3:
            litros3Asignado = litros3Asignado + i[1]
        elif i[0] == 4:
            litros4Asignado = litros4Asignado + i[1]
        elif i[0] == 5:
            litros5Asignado = litros5Asignado + i[1]
    
    print (litros1Asignado, litros2Asignado, litros3Asignado, litros4Asignado, litros5Asignado)
```

¿Cómo puedo sumar los valores de los índices que se repiten en mi primer lista, dando como resultado una lista como la que necesito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías intentar esto:

```
litrosCamionAsignado = [[5, 1329], [4, 1386], [1, 1462], [3, 1222], [2, 1445], [3, 1389], [1, 1500], [1, 1419], [5, 1355], [4, 1491], [1, 1427], [4, 1421], [3, 1259], [5, 1489], [5, 1417], [1, 1220], [1, 1291], [2, 1341], [4, 1386], [3, 1467], [1, 1429], [5, 1232], [3, 1343], [1, 1426], [4, 1332], [4, 1494], [3, 1280], [1, 1374], [2, 1376], [4, 1349]]
litrosAgrupados = [(i, [litros for (j, litros) in litrosCamionAsignado if i == j]) for i in range(1, 6)]
suma = [(i, sum(total_litros)) for (i, total_litros) in litrosAgrupados]
```

Ahí lo que estás haciendo es primero agruparlos y luego sumarlos, es decir. la variable *litrosAgrupados* quedaría así:

```
[(1, [1462, 1500, 1419, 1427, 1220, 1291, 1429, 1426, 1374]),
 (2, [1445, 1341, 1376]),
 (3, [1222, 1389, 1259, 1467, 1343, 1280]),
 (4, [1386, 1491, 1421, 1386, 1332, 1494, 1349]),
 (5, [1329, 1355, 1489, 1417, 1232])]
```

Como vez es una lista de tuplas, cada tupla contiene el índice como primer valor y los litros como segundo valor.

Otra forma quizá menos confusa si no estás familiarizado con las listas por comprensión sería con un for anidado, es decir, casi lo que tienes en tu código pero un poco más compacto.

```
for i in range(1,6):
  suma = 0
  for (j, litros) in litrosCamionAsignado:
    if i == j:
      suma = suma + litros
  totalSuma.append((i, suma))
totalSuma
```

Comment: Gracias, me ayudaste a entender mejor como asumir el problema agrupando la información.